# How to set a Range using columns and rows in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, range, user-defined-functions

Tried to get a range setup to use the worksheet function `COUNTIF`.  Here's what I've got:

```
Function count_if(work_sheet As String, criteria As String, column_num As Integer)

    Dim rows As Integer
    rows = Get_Rows_Generic(work_sheet, 1) ' get the number of rows in another sheet

    Dim full_range As Range
    With work_sheet
        Set full_range = .Range(.Cells(0, rows), .Cells(0, column_num))
    End With

    count_result = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(full_range, criteria)

    count_if = range_size
End Function

Sub test_stuff()
    Dim n As Integer
    n = count_if("usersFullOutput.csv", "TRUE", 9)
    MsgBox n
End Sub
```

When I run the code, excel asks me to choose another macro. I'm guessing it's how i'm setting the range, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Point #1**

IF "usersFullOutput.csv" is actually your worksheet's name (not a file name), with this name you cannot do this:

```
With work_sheet
    Set full_range = .Range(...)
End With
```

Range is a property of a worksheet *object*, and not a worksheet name *string*. Try doing this:

```
With Worksheets(work_sheet)
    Set full_range = .Range(...)
End With
```

**Point #2**

```
Set full_range = .Range(.Cells(0, rows), .Cells(0, column_num))
```

The first argument of `Cells()` is row number. Row number can never be `0`. The first row in Excel is always `1`. A1 would be referenced by `Cells(1, 1)`. Maybe you need something like

```
Set full_range = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rows, column_num))
```

**Point #3**

`range_size` is not defined (the line `count_if = range_size`).

I think you need

```
count_if = count_result
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but the syntax is somewhat wrong. You'd need to set the start cell and end cell, using row_index and col_index, such as:

```
Set full_range = .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(rows, column_num)
```

Let me know if that helps